# Redirecting when current time hits certain time?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
session_start();
echo "Username:".$_SESSION['username'];
echo nl2br ("\n");
echo  "College name:".$_SESSION['Collegename'];
echo nl2br ("\n");
$current=strtotime("now");
echo $current;
echo nl2br ("\n\n\n");
$sql="SELECT MAX(changetime) as max from Redirect";
$sql1=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
if (!$sql1) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli));
    exit();
}
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1);
$change=$result['max'];
echo $change;
<?php>
```

Here I want to redirect to some other page when $change will be equal to $current and for that I have to change $current again and again .I only know about setInterval function since it will be in js How can we use in php .Php being server side I guess it won't be possible.
Is there any other in which this thing can be done.

Comment: Yes, using Javascript's `setInterval()` would make most sense in this case. Since it works with an interval in milliseconds you should use PHP to compute this interval from the maximum of `changetime`, and current time, in your database table. It is simply the difference in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

if  delays the program execution for the given number of seconds

Comment: I want to redirect if both the timestamp will be equal and performing some task otherwise.